# How to convert unsigned char * to unsigned int * in c?

Tags: c

I would like to convert a unsigned char * variable to a unsigned int *. Something like this

```
unsigned char *test = 0;
unsigned int *x = test;
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Pick one! And what is the actual problem? A simple cast or conversion of a pointer type can be problematic.

Comment: *I would like to convert a unsigned char * variable to a unsigned int** -- One word question.  Why?

Comment: You can convert `unsigned char*` to `int*` with simple cast - `unsigned int* x = (unsigned int*)test;`. But it's most likely not what you want to achieve. You will receive garbage on `x` pointer dereferencing. So, question is what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cast, which in C would be

```
unsigned int *x = (unsigned int*)test;
```

But bear in mind this would be useless in your example (and in any other example I can think of) since dereferencing the pointer would give you 1, 3 or 7 bytes of undefined memory.

If you want to promote the `char` to an `unsigned int` then you would either have to store it as an `unsigned int` in the first place, or copy it onto the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works

Comment: Well "accept" it then please: that is how you give thanks here. But since the value of `test` was `NULL` it seems pointless.